# What is the value of @_current_user here?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
  def current_user
    @_current_user ||= session[:current_user_id] &&
      User.find_by_id(session[:current_user_id])
  end
```

Is @_current_user simply an id or a user object found by its id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question directly: A user object found by its id or `nil` if there is no `:current_user_id` value in the session or if no user object exists for that id.

Basically, if `@_current_user` is already set then it won't change it. Otherwise, then it checks if `session[:current_user_id]` exists/is set, and if it is, by nature of the `&&` operator, the right side is returned as the value of the expression. The right side basically looks up the user with that `current_user_id`.

Even simpler: If `@_current_user` isn't set yet, then if the session has a `current_user_id` value, it sets `@_current_user` to the `User` object matching that user id.

Comment: A small thing. Why `@_current_user` starts with `_` right after `@`? Is there any convention?

Comment: @OneZero Nah, that's not a convention that I know of (in Ruby), but it could be one being used in the application you're referring to. But yeah, it's just a convention, it has no special significance in the language.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume `session[:current_user_id]` is `5`, then the `&&` operator with the User model will return the User instance:

```
> 5 && User.new(:name => 'Foo')
=> #<User name="Foo">
```

If both sides of the `&&` operator are "truthy" (meaning neither undefined or `false`), then the right-hand side value is returned by the `&&` operator. So `@_current_user` will be the User instance.